# Platform.exit() not ending Javafx because of other threads in OSX

Tags: java, multithreading, macos, javafx, javafx-8

I have a javafx 8 app that has  multiple active thread when I want to close it, 
this code shows 8 active threads :

```
    ThreadGroup group = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
    LOG.debug("Number of active threads  = " + group.activeCount());
```

Using `Platform.exit();` and `Platform.setImplicitExit(true);` doesn't get me a clean exit.

I tried killing all threads before or after calling `Platform.exit();` but without success.

Even setting threads as deamons before interrupting didn't solve it.

```
        while (group != null) {
        group.setDaemon(true);
        group.interrupt();
        group = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
    }
```

Calling `System.exit(0)` is not an option here as other apps can be launched from within other apps or standalone.

The error shown before exit is `Not on FX application thread; currentThread = JavaFX Application Thread`.

Edit 1: the stack trace of the error :

```
    ERROR SimpleUncaughtExceptionHandler.java uncaughtException 34     [JavaFX Application Thread] Uncaught exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = JavaFX Application Thread
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:236) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:921) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at javafx.stage.Window.hide(Window.java:947) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowPeerListener.closed(WindowPeerListener.java:100) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:118) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:40) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.lambda$handleWindowEvent$423(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:150) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.handleWindowEvent(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:148) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.handleWindowEvent(Window.java:1266) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.notifyDestroy(Window.java:1183) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
```

Edit 2 : List of active threads:

```
DEBUG [JavaFX Application Thread]        isDeamon : false; name : main
DEBUG [JavaFX Application Thread]        isDeamon : true; name : QuantumRenderer-0
DEBUG [JavaFX Application Thread]        isDeamon : false; name : JavaFX-Launcher
DEBUG [JavaFX Application Thread]        isDeamon : true; name : URL-Loader-2
DEBUG [JavaFX Application Thread]        isDeamon : true; name : URL-Loader-1
DEBUG [JavaFX Application Thread]        isDeamon : true; name : JavaFX Application Thread
DEBUG [JavaFX Application Thread]        isDeamon : true; name : Java2D Queue Flusher
DEBUG [JavaFX Application Thread]        isDeamon : true; name : Prism Font Disposer
DEBUG [JavaFX Application Thread]        isDeamon : true; name : Reference Handler
DEBUG [JavaFX Application Thread]        isDeamon : true; name : Thread-6
DEBUG [JavaFX Application Thread]        isDeamon : false; name : AWT-Shutdown
DEBUG [JavaFX Application Thread]        isDeamon : true; name : Java2D Disposer
DEBUG [JavaFX Application Thread]        isDeamon : true; name : Signal Dispatcher
DEBUG [JavaFX Application Thread]        isDeamon : true; name : Disposer
DEBUG [JavaFX Application Thread]        isDeamon : true; name : Finalizer
DEBUG [JavaFX Application Thread]        isDeamon : false; name : AWT-EventQueue-0
DEBUG [JavaFX Application Thread]        isDeamon : true; name : Thread-5
DEBUG [JavaFX Application Thread]        isDeamon : true; name : Timer-0
```

Comment: What does "doesn't get me a clean exit" mean?

Comment: Exiting without the exception 'not on FX application thread ..'

Comment: @GltknBtn Don't use `thread.stop()`, **ever**. It is [inherently unsafe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop--) and has been deprecated.

Comment: If you are getting an exception, figure out why. This exception means you are updating the UI from a background thread somewhere. Check the [stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/2775450), which will tell you where that is happening.

Comment: @James_D I'm not trying to update the UI from a background thread, I'm trying to quit the application, and I have multiple active threads running.

Comment: Post the stack trace in your question.

Comment: @James_D, I know it is unsafe, But is there any way to stop a running thread safely? Thanks your advice.

Comment: @GltknBtn See the link in the documentation that I linked in the previous comment: [Why are Thread.stop ... deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

Comment: @James_D , I updated my question with the stack trace, I couldn't paste all of it as the same error is repeated.

Comment: OK, that looks very weird. You're not actually naming any of your own threads "JavaFX Application Thread", are you? Is there any of the stack trace that actually refers to code you have written? Is it possible to create a [MCVE] that reproduces this?

Comment: @James_D,  thanks for the link. Pulled back the comment.

Comment: @James_D maybe because I'm using Proguard and it obfuscates code. A minimal  complete and verifiable example would be a  javafx app with multiple threads active at the moment when Platform.exit() is called. I will try to produce one.

Comment: Perhaps first check if the error still occurs if you build it without Proguard?

Comment: @James_D , meanwhile I added the list of the active threads , see **Edit 2**.  `AWT-Shutdown` , `AWT-EventQueue-0` , `JavaFX-Launcher` and `main` are not deamons.

Comment: Is there anything in the FX application's `stop` method?

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes , some cleanup methods that close connections and delete temp files.

Comment: You should check then that the cleanup methods don't do anything GUI-related like presenting a confirmation or save dialog etc.

Answer (score 1):

This problem and [OSX System menubar not working in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42157377/osx-system-menubar-not-working-in-javafx) have the same root cause which is the splash screen I'm using "`java -splash:..`", disabling it solves the problem.

As Splash Screen is an `AWT` feature and not a `JavaFX` feature ,it seems to be launched within AWT Event Thread and not JavaFX event Thread.

It looks like that the `splash screen` in `JavaFX` should be implemented from within the application as a `JavaFX Pane`.

Comment: How bizarre, you might wish to [report a bug](http://bugreport.java.com).

Comment: @jewelsea But maybe SplashScreen isn't supposed to be used with JavaFX , or Preloader should be used instead

Comment: @jewelsea You were right, bug reported : http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8175977